# Using higher frequency data as a proxy for lower-frequency data

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have two times series - annual and quarterly. Annual data ends in 2018, but quarterly data goes till 2019q3. What's the best way to combine the two, where Python checks what's the latest available quarterly and annual data and fills annual time series with the latest quarterly value?

This is what I have in mind:

```
Data_ann
2013 5.1
2014 3.2
2015 2.1
2016 2.2
2017 2.1
2018 4.2
2019 n/a

Data_qtr
...
2018q1 2.5 
2018q2 2.2
2018q3 3.7
2018q4 4.2
2019q1 1.2
2019q2 2.3
2019q3 n/a
```

and the result

```
2013 5.1
2014 3.2
2015 2.1
2016 2.2
2017 2.1
2018 4.2
2019 2.3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can organize your data to use a `DatetimeIndex`. The yearly frame is then fine (if there's one row per year) but for the quarter DataFrame we need to take the last value in each year, accomplished with `resample.last`. `combine_first` gives us priority to the yearly DataFrame when we join them.

#### Data Prep

```
df_ann = pd.read_clipboard(header=None)
df_ann.columns = ['date', 'value']
df_ann['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_ann['date'], format='%Y')
df_ann = df_ann.set_index('date')
#            value
#date             
#2013-01-01    5.1
#2014-01-01    3.2
#2015-01-01    2.1
#2016-01-01    2.2
#2017-01-01    2.1
#2018-01-01    4.2
#2019-01-01    NaN

df_qtr = pd.read_clipboard(header=None)
df_qtr.columns = ['date', 'value']
df_qtr['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_qtr['date'])
df_qtr = df_qtr.set_index('date')
#            value
#date             
#2018-01-01    2.5
#2018-04-01    2.2
#2018-07-01    3.7
#2018-10-01    4.2
#2019-01-01    1.2
#2019-04-01    2.3
#2019-07-01    NaN
```

#### Code

```
df_ann.to_period('Y').combine_first(df_qtr.resample('Y').last().to_period('Y'))

      value
date       
2013    5.1
2014    3.2
2015    2.1
2016    2.2
2017    2.1
2018    4.2
2019    2.3
```

Comment: When I run the code I get an error message: raise ValueError(_INVALID_FREQ_ERROR.format(freq))

ValueError: Invalid frequency: Y

Comment: @Ziablik does it work if you change the `'Y'` to `'A'` in all of them? What version of pandas are you running?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6 and changing 'Y' to 'A' did work like a charm! Thank you very much!